# How I can truncate and shrink the Logs file in mirroring (Full Recovery model)?

Tags: transaction-log, mirroring, shrink

I am trying to truncate and shrink the database. I have taken the backup of transaction logs and now trying to shrink but it's executing with No effect.

I have used dbcc shrinkfile(). Please help